# How to store the values of a function in a file

Tags: functions, export, import

As it is well known, it is possible to define a function that remembers its values once its evaluated, using the following code:

```
f[x_]:=f[x]=rhs
```

During the day I evaluate `f[x]`, for many `x`'s, and I do not know/remember at which values of `x` I evaluated this. These values wont need to be evaluated again until I close mathematica, but if I close it, they will be lost. Is there a way to avoid this? To store these values somehow, so that I can use them the next time I open mathematica?

Comment: `save = DownValues[f]` places the arguments and corresponding values of `f` in `save`.

Comment: Look at documentation for [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon  Much better than my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I think DumpSave is storing only the definitions of the functions. The evaluations seem to be lost